# Image in ListView Expand to ListView container size keeping aspect ratio

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I am making kind of a picture carousel in my app using a `ListView` with horizontal scrolling.

The height of my `ListView` is binded to the window, so it can change.

My images are always way bigger than the height of my view and I can't figure out how to make sure the image dosen't take more space than it has.

(height should be = height of the `ListView`  - the height of the `Checkbox` - height of the `ScrollBar`)

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" Margin="18,226,15,10" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" CanVerticallyScroll="False" >
            <CheckBox Content="Select" />
            <Image  Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
               <Image.InputBindings>
                 <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source}"/>
               </Image.InputBindings>
            </Image> 
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" CanVerticallyScroll="False"></StackPanel>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: A StackPanel does not resize its child elements. Use a different Panel in the ItemTemplate, e.g. a Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that a `StackPanel` has no notion of available space. It just stacks its children and if there is not enough space to accomodate them, they will be cut-off by the containing element.

In order to make your images size to fit the available space, you could use a [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) with two rows. The first using a `Height` of `Auto` to make it take only as much space as the `CheckBox` needs and the second using the default size of one star to take up the remaining space.

> Columns and rows that are defined within a `Grid` can take advantage of Star sizing to **distribute remaining space proportionally**. When Star is selected as the height or width of a row or column, that column or row receives a weighted proportion of the remaining available space.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <CheckBox Content="Select"/>
      <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
         <Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source}"/>
         </Image.InputBindings>
      </Image> 
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Alternatively, you can use a [`DockPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) with [`LastChildFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) set to `true` (default).

> If you set the `LastChildFill` property to `true`, which is the default setting, **the last child element of a `DockPanel` always fills the remaining space**, regardless of any other dock value that you set on the last child element.

```
<DataTemplate>
   <DockPanel>
      <CheckBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Select"/>
      <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
         <Image.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source}"/>
         </Image.InputBindings>
      </Image> 
   </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: That works perfectly thank you. Might not be related but  do you know if there is a way to keep the Grid or DockPanel square  (the height is auto sized and keep the with the same as ActualHeight)?